# Can I redirect_to a javascript request to another javascript action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox

I have a comments controller with index and create actions among others. Both those actions respond to html and js format.

Whenever I got create request via ajax, I would like to add new comment and then redirect to index.js, so the comments on screen are updated without reloading the page.

This sort of thing works flawlesly in Chrome. But whenever I try this in Firefox or IE, it turns out, that the redirect from create.js lands in index.html...

Even when i force the redirect to be js:

```
redirect_to polymorphic_path([@commentable, :comments]), :format => 'js'
```

It land up in the format.html in Firefox and IE.

Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Isn't :format => js supposed to be in polymorphic_path polymorphic_path([@commentable, :comments], :format => 'js')

Comment: Exactly it should. It turned out that this way format is properly forced, so I used redirect_to polymorphic_path([@commentable, :comments], :format => request.format.to_sym) in most actions. The general problem is, that Webkit browsers like Chrome or Safari keep the request type when they get 302 redirect. Firefox and IE forget the type after request, so it has to be manualy set.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues with the way browsers handle 302 requests differently. Some lose request types, others lose request method (an example ticket: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/160).

I would suggest that rather than redirecting to a new URL when using JS, you simply render the same action. So something like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index 
    setup_for_index
    respond_to :html, :js
  end

  def create
    # Creation stuff...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :action => :index}
      format.js do
        setup_for_index
        render :action => :index
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def setup_for_index
    @comments = ...
  end
end
```